# IE10 - textbox attribute disabled/enabled

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, internet-explorer-10

I have textboxes that when the user click on one of the textbox, all other textboxes will be disabled. It is working fine in firefox, what i can not understand is that, the enabling of the textbox doesn't work in IE10 (i cannot edit the value inside the textbox when enable(?). Below are my jquery codes, am i missing something for IE10? i have tried .prop('disable', false), .prop('readOnly', false) but nothing works in IE10 but in firefox i have no problem. please help.

Textbox onclick event:

```
function DisableTboxExceptActiveTxbox(txtbox) {
  $('input[id*="tbxQty"]').attr("disabled", true);
  $(txtbox).removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Cancel Button onclick event:

```
function CancelUpdate(btn) {
  $('input[id*="tbxOrderQty_"]').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `.prop('disabled', true|false)` when disabling or enabling the textboxes, not `attr('disabled', true)` and `removeAttr('disabled')`. So the proper code would be:

```
function DisableTboxExceptActiveTxbox(txtbox) {
  $('input[id*="tbxQty"]').prop("disabled", true);
  $(txtbox).prop("disabled", false);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

It appears that the first statement is causing IE 10 and 11 to make the current textbox disabled, and despite the second line removing the `disabled` property, IE re-adds it when you start interacting with the text box. You can see this when you look at the DOM Explorer while running the code.

Try this code instead:

```
function DisableTboxExceptActiveTxbox(txtbox) {
  $('input[id*="tbxQty"]').not(txtbox).prop("disabled", true);
}
```

See also this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pX6Kv/2/

This selects all of the textboxes, then filters out the current textbox, then sets the remaining to disabled. Interesting bug. I'll file it with Microsoft, if it's not already.

---

You should consider adding a class to each of these textboxes rather than using `[id*="tbxQty"]`, as it would be faster in most browsers.

Then, the CancelUpdate:

```
function CancelUpdate(btn) {
  $('input[id*="tbxOrderQty_"]').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

You may also want to be more consistent how you're going to abbreviate "textbox", as `tbx`, `txtbox`, `Tbox` or `Txbox` are all used. Just a suggestion though :)

Comment: i've already tried those but they wont work also in IE10. It does works in firefox but not in IE10.

Comment: Here's a working version of this kind of thing: http://jsfiddle.net/pX6Kv/ can you confirm whether that works in IE10? If so, it may be a problem in how your handlers are bound to the text boxes themselves.

Comment: it is definitely the IE10. your jsfiddle doesnt work also there.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? When I run that jsfiddle in IE10, I get two text boxes and a button. When I click into one of the text boxes, the other is disabled. When I click the button, both become enabled.

Comment: you cannot key-in a value in the textbox. is the editing of value differs from the enabled attribute of the textbox?

Comment: i mean, when you say textbox is enabled part of it being enabled is that you can key-in value right? because if this is not the case, if you're telling me that the color is not gray means it is enabled. then i should be really missing some attributes with the textbox to get it accept value.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're seeing now... Fascinating. IE10 (and IE11, BTW) doesn't seem to clear the property fully. It appears enabled, but is in fact disabled (the disabled attribute appears in the DOM Explorer). I'll amend my answer. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pX6Kv/2/

Comment: clever! its working... very nice idea of isolating the active textbox from being disabled... i'll try it and give feedback... thanks a lot...

Answer (score -1):

Let me know if this changes anything:

```
function DisableTboxExceptActiveTxbox(txtbox) {    
  $("input[type=text]").click(function (e) {
    $("input[type=text]").attr("disabled", true);
    $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm, Could you paste the html code after you click?  Just to see how the markup is...